# Calculate similarity matrix for the 1st column

Tags: r, matrix, similarity, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I have started working on a few ML projects and use R as the preferred language. I am trying to build a basic recommendation system

http://www.dataperspective.info/2014/05/basic-recommendation-engine-using-r.html

I need to find the similarity matrix (according to the website) and using cosine function (in 'lsa' package) to find user_similarity.

```
library(lsa)
data_rating <- read.csv("recommendation_basic1.csv", header = TRUE)

x = data_rating[,2:7]
x[is.na(x)] = 0
print(x)

similarity_users <- cosine(as.matrix(x))
similarity_users
```

But I need to find the similarity matrix among users and this code is giving me an output similarity matrix among the movies. Do I need to modify the below line?

```
x = data_rating[,2:7]
```

PS. The recommendation_basic1.csv is the same as in the link.

Comment: `cosine(t(as.matrix(x)))`   ?

Comment: Hey thanks, that worked.
What does that 't' do though? Sorry if it's a lame question

Comment: t = transpose   (of a matrix)  In this case,  it will simply switch the role of users and movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this in so the question is not unanswered.

You can just use   `similarity_users <- cosine(as.matrix(t(x)))`
Here, the `t` is matrix transpose,  so it just switches the rows and columns  which is equivalent to switching the users and the movies.